# How to overload the functions "[<-.ffdf" and "[.ffdf" from package ff (in R)?

Tags: r, overloading, ff, ffbase

I've experienced the write error from ff package. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025202/ff-package-write-error) suggests that the solution could be to overload the functions "[<-.ffdf" and "[.ffdf". Could somebody elaborate this in more details, or at least suggest what I need to figure out to understand what is necessary to accomplish this. Keep in mind that this the question comes from a novice.

Answer (score 2):

Just rewrite the "[<-.ffdf" and "[.ffdf" functions.

```
require(ff)
## For the assignment
get("[<-.ffdf")
args(get("[<-.ffdf"))
"[<-.ffdf" <- function (x, i, j, value){
  ## put your code in here and make sure it does not open too many ff files which are in x
}
## For the getter
args(get("[.ffdf"))
"[.ffdf" <- function (x, i, j, drop = ncols == 1){
  ## put your code in here and make sure it does not open too many ff files which are in x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution would be to increase your systems setting to allow for more files to be open simultaneously.  That system setting is the limiting factor for the ff data frame.  I explained how to change this setting [on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40936833/809198).